# Scroll view scrolling horizontally when it shouldn't

Tags: swift3, scroll

My app is only a landscape app. My View Controller has a view that has a scroll view that has a content view. I really only want the scroll to scroll up and down and not left and right because all overflow content will be added to the bottom.

When I deploy, my app scrolls left and right as well which doesn't display any data and can only cause confusion to the user.

DIMENSIONS
View: w:667, h: 375
Scroll View: w: 667, h: 355 with a starting Y of 20
Content View: w:667, h: 600

Not sure where to go at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Like this,

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.x>0 {
        scrollView.contentOffset.x = 0
    }
}
```

And, you can set this property:

```
scrollImg.directionalLockEnabled = true
```